# File not found on linux build machine because of case

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, node-modules, case-sensitive

My angular app uses some npm packages.
These packages contain some imports to case-sensitive file names.

For example:

I'm importing `something` from the `@lib`:

```
import { something} from '@lib';
```

And in `something` (which is a module in an npm package), there is an import to another module:

```
import { subModule } from './subModule';
```

Because of the case of subModule, it throws that module is not found.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You need to fix EVERY case mistaken names to proper ones. There is no way around it. Unix systems are case-sensitive, windows is not (easier) but that means, you need to be very cautious about using proper cases for files and directories of imports in node (and not only)

Comment: It's not my code. the case-sensitive file is in an npm package. How can I fix it?
Should I use an other package?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is that package?   and sadly, yes probably use other. You can fork it, fix it - push the pr to the owner, but for time being use the forked one

Comment: It's an internal package in my company. Maybe there is a way to use webpack to provide the file?

Comment: Then tell the owner to fix that (best way).

Comment: As for ,,hacks'' that can destroy the project in future, you can try to make symlinks (like after installing everything, add a script that will make symbolic links inside the module, so every messed up file would be present) [['postinstall' script in package.json]]